# rewrite rule issue in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rule which is working

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(step)/([0-9]+)/(id)/([0-9]+)/(start)/([0-9]+)/(end)/
([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now I wanted to add another param at the end of the string which is **(ansid)** so I did in the following way but for some reason it is not picking up the ansid.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(step)/([0-9]+)/(id)/([0-9]+)/(start)/([0-9]+)/(end)
/([0-9]+)/(ansid)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 
[NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$10` and `$11` won't work because as per [Apache mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

**RewriteRule backreferences:**
These are backreferences of the form $N (0 <= N <= 9). $1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions. $0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.

You need to refactor your rule to use backreference upto `$9`
Your rule can be possibly rewritten as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(step)/([0-9]+)/(id)/([0-9]+)/(start)/([0-9]+)/end/([0-9]+)/ansid/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&end=$8&$ansid=$9 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks.So you mean I have to restructure the url so that it limits within 0-9. In that case I think I have to remove one param.

Comment: Yes that is true you cannot use backreference number > 9.

Comment: ahh now I have understood the story. Thank you so much for explaining this and the suggestion.